# Inertia coprime to degree implies Inertia cyclic?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions, ramification

Let $K$ be a number field and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime of $K$ co-prime to 2. Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of degree a power of 2. Let $I$ denote the inertia group for $\mathfrak{p}$ relative to $L/K$.

**Prove (or disprove and salvage if possible) that $I$ is cyclic. (Do I need additional assumptions on $K$ to ensure that $I$ is cyclic?)**

This should just be standard algebraic number theory coming from tame ramification at $\mathfrak{p}$, but I am having trouble finding a reference that makes this clear.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify. I'm not looking for a proof so much as good references to use in this proof.

Answer (score 2):

Corollary 7.59 in Chapter 7 of [Milne's Algebraic Number Theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf) is what I was looking for. Thanks!